# MIgraciones asignan valor por Default

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core

estoy trabajando en un proyecto con C#, Entity Framework y MySQL.
 Queria saber si me podrian ayudar con un "problema" que estoy teniendo con  migraciones.
Estaba trabajando con la version MySQL 5.6 y pase a la version  5.7, el problema(si se puede decir problema) es que ahora para los tipo de datos Guid me asigna un valor por default, lo cual necesitaria que no haga

MySQL 5.6

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.AddColumn<Guid>(
        name: "UserId",
        table: "Policy",
        nullable: false
}
```

MySQL 5.7

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.AddColumn<Guid>(
        name: "CompanyId",
        table: "Policy",
        nullable: false,
        defaultValue: new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"));
}
```

Como podria evitar que asigne un valor por default en la migracion sin tener que editar el archivo de migracion? Se podria?

Answer (score 1):

Podrias intentar cambiar la propiedad en el modelo de tu entidad Policy `Guid CompanyId` a `Guid? CompanyId`

Al declarar CompanyId como nullable(`Guid?`) no requiere valor por defecto y al generar la migracion le saldra :

```
 migrationBuilder.AddColumn(
            name: "CompanyId",
            table: "Policy",
            nullable: true,
            defaultValue: null);
```

Comment: Para que tu respuesta sea mejor recibida explica mejor tu respuesta